# How to split based on multiple delimiter pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df column which contains

```
Phone number
12399422/930201021
5451354;546325642
789888744,656313214
123456654
```

I would like to separate it into two columns

```
Phone number1      Phone number2
12399422           930201021
5451354            546325642
789888744          656313214
123456654
```

I have tried to use apply,

```
    df['TELEPHONE1'] = df['TELEPHONE'].str.split(',').str.get(0)
    df['TELEPHONE2'] = df['TELEPHONE'].str.split(',').str.get(1)
    df['TELEPHONE1'] = df['TELEPHONE'].str.split(';').str.get(0)
    df['TELEPHONE2'] = df['TELEPHONE'].str.split(';').str.get(1)
    df['TELEPHONE1'] = df['TELEPHONE'].str.split('/').str.get(0)
    df['TELEPHONE2'] = df['TELEPHONE'].str.split('/').str.get(1)
```

but it can only split '/' Thank you for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `str.split`

```
df.Phonenumber.str.split('/|;|,',expand=True).add_prefix('Number_')
    Number_0   Number_1
0   12399422  930201021
1    5451354  546325642
2  789888744  656313214
3  123456654       None
```

Comment: I'm using this `df[ColumnName].str.split('[,]',expand=True)`, but doesn't recognize that I have three separators. It either separates every single character or only separates by comma.

Answer (score 3):

Just split on `\D` (non-digit):

```
(df['Phone number'].str.split(r'\D', expand=True)
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'num{x+1}'))

        num1       num2
0   12399422  930201021
1    5451354  546325642
2  789888744  656313214
3  123456654       None
```

...Under the assumption that phone numbers only contain digits.

---

Alternatively, use `extractall` and match digits only:

```
df['Phone number'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0].unstack()

match          0          1
0       12399422  930201021
1        5451354  546325642
2      789888744  656313214
3      123456654        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.Phonenumber.str.split('[\/\|\;\|\,]',expand=True).add_prefix('Number_')
```

this should be the right answer