# Split cells in one column by comma into multiple rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For an input data as follows, I want to split column `office_number` by comma into multiple rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1010084420','1010084420','1010084420','1010084421','1010084421','1010084421','1010084425'],
                   'building_name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'East Tower', 'East Tower', 'West Tower', 'T1'],
                   'floor': ['1', '1', '2', '10', '10', '11','11'],
                   'office_number':['101-105', '106', '201-203, 205, 208', '1001-1005', '1006, 1008, 1010', '1101-1103', '1101-1105'],
                   'company_name': ['Ariel Resources Ltd.', 'A.O. Tatneft', '', 'Agrium Inc.', 'Creo Products Inc.', 'Cott Corp.', 'Creo Products Inc.']})
```

This is my solution with reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe):

```
res = (df.set_index(['id', 'building_name', 'floor', 'company_name'])
   .stack()
   .str.split(',', expand=True)
   .stack()
   .unstack(-2)
   .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index())

result = res[['id', 'building_name', 'floor', 'office_number', 'company_name']]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
            id building_name floor office_number          company_name
0   1010084420             A     1           106          A.O. Tatneft
1   1010084420             A     1       101-105  Ariel Resources Ltd.
2   1010084420             A     2       201-203                      
3   1010084420             A     2           205                      
4   1010084420             A     2           208                      
5   1010084421    East Tower    10     1001-1005           Agrium Inc.
6   1010084421    East Tower    10          1006    Creo Products Inc.
7   1010084421    East Tower    10          1008    Creo Products Inc.
8   1010084421    East Tower    10          1010    Creo Products Inc.
9   1010084421    West Tower    11     1101-1103            Cott Corp.
10  1010084425            T1    11     1101-1105    Creo Products Inc.
```

If you have any other solutions, welcome to share. Thanks.

Comment: There si something bad with this solution? What is reason for another solutions?

Comment: No, it's good, just wonder if there are other solutions. BTW, I have tried accepted solution from reference link, it doesn't work out.

Comment: it is not possible (because you dont ask question there), but you can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is extract column by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), `split`, `stack` for `Series` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
s = (df.pop('office_number')
       .str.split(',', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(1, drop=True)
       .rename('office_number'))

res = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
result = res[['id', 'building_name', 'floor', 'office_number', 'company_name']]

print(result)
            id building_name floor office_number          company_name
0   1010084420             A     1       101-105  Ariel Resources Ltd.
1   1010084420             A     1           106          A.O. Tatneft
2   1010084420             A     2       201-203                      
3   1010084420             A     2           205                      
4   1010084420             A     2           208                      
5   1010084421    East Tower    10     1001-1005           Agrium Inc.
6   1010084421    East Tower    10          1006    Creo Products Inc.
7   1010084421    East Tower    10          1008    Creo Products Inc.
8   1010084421    East Tower    10          1010    Creo Products Inc.
9   1010084421    West Tower    11     1101-1103            Cott Corp.
10  1010084425            T1    11     1101-1105    Creo Products Inc.
```

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question, if I need to split cells by more than one delimiters besides comma, slash for example, what should I do? I try with `s = (df.pop('office_number')
       .str.split('/' or ',', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(1, drop=True)
       .rename('office_number'))` but I got an KeyError.

Comment: @ahbon - You need `|` for regex or - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605756/2901002