# append new columns with elements of another columns dataframe Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append

[screenshot of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prdRQ.png)

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One of these contains names of french suppliers like "Intermarché", "Carrefour", "Leclerc" (as you can see in the framed column on the attached screenshot). Unfortunately, the names are typed by hand and are not standardized at all. From the "Distributeurs" column, I would like to create a new column with the names unified in a list by cell so that I can then use the fonction .explore() and make one product and one distributor per row. I would like to make a selection of about 30 supplies and put 'others suppliers' for the rest. I feel like I have to use regular expressions and loops but I'm totally lost. Could someone help me? Thanks

I try this but I'm lost :

```html
df['test']=''
distrib_list=["Leclerc","Monoprix",'Franprix','Intermarché','Carrefour','Lidl','Proxi','Grand Frais','Fresh','Cora','Casino',"Relais d'Or",'Biocoop','Métro','Match','Super U','Aldi','Spar','Colruyt','Auchan']
for n in df['Distributeurs']:
    if n in distrib_list:
        df['test'].append
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first split your `Distributeurs` with the comma by doing something along the lines of `df['Distributeurs'].str.split(',')`. Once that is done you can iterate over the rows of your dataframe, get the idx and the row in question. Then you can iterate over your splitted `Distributeur` cell. I also make it case insensitive (for unicode you might need to add things to this if statment).

Then you can create a new dataframe with this information (and add whatever other information you wish) by creating first a list and transforming it into a dataframe. This can be accomplished with something on the lines of:

```py
import pandas as pd
test = []

distList = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
data = [['Product1', ['Name1', 'Name2']], ['Product2', ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']], ['Product3', ['Name4', 'Name5']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Product', 'Distributor'])

for idx, x in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(x['Distributor'])):
        if x['Distributor'][i].lower() in distList :
            test.append({
                'Product':df['Product'][idx],
                'Distributor':x['Distributor'][i]
                })
        else:
            pass
        
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. the problem is that not all cells have "," as a separator. Sometimes it's just a space, sometimes it's a "/", sometimes it's not even a space and everything is attached...

Comment: Then the problem becomes which regular expression to use. Regular expressions can have multiple different delimiters like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605744/how-to-split-based-on-multiple-delimiter-pandas). However, if your data has no regular expression, you might need to manually fix it before running a code on it.